# Basis of intersection of two vectorspaces is not in original vectorspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having troubles understanding following problem:

Find a basis for $U \cap V$ with:

\begin{equation*}
    U = \text{span}\big\{ \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}}_{= \vec{u}_1},\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{= \vec{u}_2}\big\}
    \qquad\qquad
    V = \text{span}\big\{ \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{=\vec{v}_1},\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}}_{= \vec{v}_2}\big\}
\end{equation*}

I know that I have to find solutions to this equation:
\begin{equation}
    \vec{0} = \alpha \vec{u}_1 + \beta \vec{u}_2 - \gamma \vec{v}_1 - \epsilon \vec{u}_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \vec{u}_1 & \vec{u}_2 & -\vec{v}_1 & -\vec{v}_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \\ \epsilon
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
    U \cap V &= \text{ker}\begin{pmatrix} \vec{u}_1 & \vec{u}_2 & -\vec{v}_1 & -\vec{v}_2 \end{pmatrix} = 
    \text{ker}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix}\\
    &=\text{ker}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    =\text{ker}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix} \\ &= 
    \text{ker}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \text{span} \big\{ \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\big\} =\text{span}\big\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}\big\}
\end{align}

Now I found a basis and therefore I'm done with the problem.

However, how can this vector be a basis of $U \cap V$ if it is clear to see that:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \notin U
    \qquad\qquad
    \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \notin V
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when you solve the equation below:

\begin{equation}
    \vec{0} = \alpha \vec{u}_1 + \beta \vec{u}_2 - \gamma \vec{v}_1 - \epsilon \vec{u}_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \vec{u}_1 & \vec{u}_2 & -\vec{v}_1 & -\vec{v}_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \\ \epsilon
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

You find all the **scalars** which defines the vectors in the intersection between U and V but not the **vectors**.
Hence, you should use the scalars you found to obtain the vectors, Choose:
$\alpha = 1$, $\beta = 1$ for the vectors in U basis, and $\gamma = -1$, $\epsilon = 1$ for the vectors in V basis, and you will get:
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ 1 \\-1 \\ 1
    \end{pmatrix} which is indeed in U∩V.